# Update a list from a function in Python

Tags: python, list, function, definition

I would like to update a list defined outside a function as below:

```
import pandas as pd

list1=[]
list2=[]
list3=[]

def updatelist():
     list1=['one','two','three']
     list2=['1','2','3']
     list3=['4','5','6']

df1=pd.DataFrame(list1)
df2=pd.DataFrame(list2)
df3=pd.DataFrame(list3)
```

When I try printing the list I am seeing empty lists. The function is not updating the list values.

Note : The definition performs certain calculations to update the list and cannot be done outside the definition.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You never call `updatelist`?

Comment: You're assigning to local variables, not the global variables.

Comment: For the first line of your function write `global list1, list2, list3`. This will make the subsequent assignments to the global variables rather than creating new local variables.

Comment: better use `return list1, list2, list3` and later `list1, list2, list3 = updatelist()`

Answer (score 0):

Update your code as follows,

```
import pandas as pd

list1=[]
list2=[]
list3=[]

def updatelist():
    global list1,list2,list3
    list1=['one','two','three']
    list2=['1','2','3']
    list3=['4','5','6']


updatelist()
df1=pd.DataFrame(list1)
df2=pd.DataFrame(list2)
df3=pd.DataFrame(list3)
```

You need to define list variables as global before accessing them from a method

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your list as a global inside your function

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []

def updatelist():
     global list1
     global list2
     global list3
     list1=['one','two','three']
     list2=['1','2','3']
     list3=['4','5','6']

updatelist() # Function is modifying your lists outside i.e globally
```

Now if you do

```
print(list1, list2, list3)
```

you will get

```
['one','two','three'] ['1','2','3'] ['4','5','6']
```